# Getting context in ember templates in singular resource index outlet

Tags: ember.js

**I just want to be able to display a campaign model's properties in the templates rendered in the my resource template's outlet.**

My router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map (match)->
  @resource 'campaigns', ->
    @resource 'campaign',
      path: ':campaign_id', ->
        @route 'chat',
          path: '/chat'
```

**I set up 3 templates for my campaign resource:**

- campaign
- campaign.index
- campaign.chat

I am not sure how I am supposed to get acces to the model identified by the dynamic segment in my url. I was able to set it up successfully in my campaign route like so:

```
App.CampaignRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> App.Campaign.find(params.campaign_id)
```

This doesn't seem to work for the index and chat routes.

I was thinking something like {{someProperty}} or {{campaign.someProperty}} would work by default here.

**Why does the context change and how do I get it?**

My routes and templates are rendering fine, minus the context I want.

Answer (score 0):

*Setting the model this way in my campaign.index and campaign.chat routes made all the difference:*

```
App.CampaignIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> 
    @modelFor('campaign')

App.CampaignChatRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> 
    @modelFor('campaign')
```